# Laravel count numbers based on more than one tables

Tags: laravel, count, pivot

I have 3 tables, *products*, *orders* and *order_product*, *order_product* is a pivoting table that maps products and orders based on *product_id* and *order_id*. Given a product_id, I want to find out the total sales of this product, here's what's in my mind: find out all the orders that contains this product_id, and if any of the orders have the status *completed*, then the product is sold for this order, now how should I write my query using ->count()? By the way, I have all the models and relationships setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Product::find(1)->orders()->where('orders.status', 'completed')->count()
```

Comment: Only orders containing a given product should be taken into account, not just all completed orders.

Comment: What is the "order" in where clause? Is it model name? My model name for orders is Order, in that case, should I use Order instead of order?

Comment: @dulan No it's the table name.. wait, just noticed you have `orders` so it would be `orders.status`. actually just `status` should work too. as long your products table doesn't have a status as well

Comment: @dulan no problem :) just out of curiosity, does both work, `orders.status` and `status`?

Comment: Yes they do, both of them.